# How can I specify the file_data_directories for a keyspace

Tags: cassandra

When I defines several file_data_directories in cassandra.yaml, would it be possible to specify the location keyspace and tables ? or it is automatically managed by Cassandra.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to define specific mount points that map to Cassandra's directory structure (i.e. [data]/keyspace/...). This is not a great solution, but there's no other way to do it now.